# change colour of desktop icon name in gnome ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: themes, colors, desktop-icons, icon-themes, gnome-tweaks

I want to change icon name color from white to black.
I have already tried theme settings through gnome tweaks.
I am using Adwaita(default) for applications and icons.

[image]

I have now changed the icons theme to LoginIcons but the problem still persists.